# SSIS passing custom objects

Tags: object, casting, ssis

I've created a custom class in one of my flow tasks and assign values to it's properties.
I store the collection of these custom classes in the Object variable
Later on in a different script task i want to read the values from this collection of custom objects.

The custom class is unknown in the other ssis components.  I can't create a dll and store it on the SQL server so how to a transport the collection of custom objects.

I can get them to the script tasks and they have all the properties and correct values but there doesn't appear to be a way to accesss the properties. I duplicated the custom class and tried casting it but SSIS knows it's not the same one and won't play ball.

how do i access this data?

Erick

Comment: One way I have  done is Serialize .net Objects as XML or base64 encoded strings and we all know how to pass string in SSIS control or data flow. Here is the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in fact you cannot create either a custom DLL or a custom SSIS component, your only alternative will be to use [.NET reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.reflection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in your consuming scripts to find the appropriate methods/properties and access them dynamically.

That will be a significant amount of work, and the programming environment offered by SSIS isn't really conducive to it. If you really cannot deploy non-package code to your servers, I'd seriously rethink the architecture that needs that custom class.

EDIT: Simple access wasn't as hard as I thought it might be. Assuming you have a package-level variable of type `Object` named "SomeObject", you could build a control flow like this:
[image: demonstration control flow for passing object variables]

The code for SCR_SetVariables is:

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_00e1230a50e6470e8324a14e9d36f6c7.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion
        class SomeClass
        {
            public string Greeting { get; set; }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return String.Format("My greeting is {0}", this.Greeting);
            }
        }
        public void Main()
        {
            SomeClass myClass = new SomeClass();
            myClass.Greeting = "Hello, world!";
            Dts.Variables["SomeObject"].Value = myClass;
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

and the code for SCR_ShowVariables is:

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ST_eea68a39bda44e9d9afaa07d2e48fc0f.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion
        public void Main()
        {
            object someObject = Dts.Variables["SomeObject"].Value;
            PropertyInfo getGreeting = someObject.GetType().GetProperty("Greeting");
            string greeting = (string)getGreeting.GetValue(someObject, null);
            string msg = String.Format("someObject.Greeting = '{0}'", greeting);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(msg);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

This will show the following messagebox:

[image: resulting messagebox displaying "Hello, world!"]

Comment: Thanks that's exactly how i ended up doing it.  For some reason i thought that using reflexion required a lot of code when in fact its just a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to properly use a custom class library in your SSIS project (to be able to use it across the whole package), you have to sign your assembly with the strong name. And add it to GAC. I don't know any other way. And then you can reference it from your project.

Another thing is you have to use the properly scoped variable to stuff your object diagram somewhere. Then you are able to retreive it later, e.g. in some other script task.

HTH

P.S. [see this](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/05/referencing-custom-assembly-inside.html), in the end it says where to put the dll so maybe you don't have to sign it after all (?!?)

Comment: sorry but i cannot deploy dll's accross our entire organisation for one project.  As all our server environments must be standardized adding a dll anywhere would take a change in policy.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to store your data in DataSet object - this way you can always access your data in other script task / components.
So e.g. in your first script task store your data with

```
...
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("Data");
DataTable table = dataSet.Tables.Add("Table");
Dts.Variables["VariableOfTypeObject"].Value = dataSet;
...
```

and in the other script task access it via

```
Dataset myData = Dts.Variables{"VariableOfTypeObject"].Value as DataSet;
```

Alternatively, if you are looking for a native way to store data in a SSIS variable of type object within a dataflow you can use the "Recordset Destination".

Comment: Downvoted because the claim that "The object type of SSIS variables is not a .NET object, it is a masqueraded ADO.NET DataSet." is utter nonsense. The Object type **is** a .NET Object.

Comment: When you try to store any other object type in an SSIS variable of type object, and when you set a breakpoint in debug mode and add the variable to your watch list, the debugger will present it to you as something like a COM-object. Only when you pass a dataset into this variable it will work as expected. That's why I wrote it is a masqueraded .net-Object. See also here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/30a13b29-4f19-4921-ae8f-810359a80416/ssis-return-list-of-custom-objects-after-a-script-task?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: I corrected my answer - you proved it above, the SSIS object variable it is a real .Net object. But if you are in debug mode, if you are trying to have a look into the SSIS variable, it will only work for DataSets... And for DataSets you don't need to go via reflection, you can easily access your object in other script taks / components.

Comment: Removed the downvote after the edit to remove the inaccurate claim.

Comment: Actually i even thought about persisting the data to a table and then reading it later on back out.  Slows things down but it is easy to do. In the end i used reflection which was just as easy.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create a .Net library project, **added it to the GAC** and reference it in your scripts if you don't what to go the route of reflection.