# SSIS Script task `Invalid cast exception` at retrieving complex object from variables

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, dynamics-crm-2013, script-task

## Prerequisites:

I want to connect to MS Dynamics CRM web services at the beginning of package execution and reuse the connection all over the package, but I failed to do that via SSIS Variables.

I can't use Connection manager because i use `OrganizationService.Execute` method that is not supported by WebService Task wizard

## Steps:

1. Added Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk dll's to GAC and to script references;
2. Created dataflow task and two separate script tasks inside
3. Created 2 package variables `crmOrganizationService` and `crmOrganizationServiceProxy`

   - both of type `System.Object`
   - `script task 1` and `script task 2` can read-write them
4. Inside of `script task 1`:

   - Instantiate  `OrganizationServiceProxy` and `OrganizationService` and connect to MS Dynamics CRM Web services.
   - Assign both instances of objects to variables

     `//create 
     public OrganizationServiceProxy _serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(orgServiceManagement, adCredentials);
     public IOrganizationService _service =(IOrganizationService)_serviceProxy;
     //assign
     this.Variables.crmOrganizationServiceProxy= _serviceProxy;
     this.Variables.crmOrganizationService=_service;`
5. Inside of `script task 2`:

   `OrganizationServiceProxy _serviceProxy = (OrganizationServiceProxy)this.Variables.crmOrganizationServiceProxy`

## Error:

At step 5 I receive Invalid cast exception because of inability to cast `System.Object` as `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy`

## Workaround:

I'm sure the problem is in basic boxing of variables while passing them between script tasks. Yet I didn't find a better general approach. Within it, I need to pass instances of custom classes between script-tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Reflection or a custom SSIS component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698626/ssis-passing-custom-objects) but maybe doing that is not worth it.

The other option would be to host an interim web service between your SSIS package and CRM, and cache the connection in the webservice. Maybe that's a lot easier for you.